# Different notification tone only for one contact

Tags: notifications, lg-g2

I want to have a different notification tone for one specific contact, but I can't figure it out.

I can change the tone only for All Contacts, but not for only for one contact.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a specific ringtone as detailed below. For message notifications you will need to find a messages app that supports that option.

To define contact-specific ringtones:
From the `contacts` app open the `Groups Tab`. Create a new group with the phone numbers that belong to the contact (home, work, cellular, etc.). Select `Ringtone` and choose the tone you want for this contact.